# Intellij Idea Live Templates

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, live-templates

I faced with the problem of writing my vcs current branch name each time I have written 'todo' comment.

Recently I learned about Intellij's 'Live Templates' which is quite comfortable to use. I tried to apply it to my problem but there's no templates to take out a branch name.

So the question is could I actually take out the name of my branch to code comments somehow?

Comment: Could you describe the problem more specifically? I can not say that I fully understood it.

Comment: @AxelP well, I must to write my current branch name in 'todo' comment (like 'todo [feature-xxx]: <my_todo_comment>') each time I want to leave a comment somewhere in a code. And it's actually a bit boring so I want to generate 'todo' template automatically (as I understood Live Templates, you only start writing a special key word and then full template will be generated).

In search of acceptable template I didn't find any way to do that (I couldn't found any function to find out which branch is currently used).

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to use the groovyScript predefined function and a script to extract the branch name. For example create the following live template:

```
$COMMENT$ todo [$BRANCH$]: $END$
```

with abbreviation "todo" and description "Inserts todo comment with branch name". Click *Edit variables* and give the variables the following definitions:

COMMENT:

```
lineCommentStart()
```

BRANCH (updated for 2020.2 and newer)

```
groovyScript("com.intellij.dvcs.repo.VcsRepositoryManager.getInstance(_editor.project).getRepositoryForFileQuick(com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getFile(_editor.document)).getCurrentBranchName()")
```

*Skip if defined* checked for both variables. The Groovy script is (unfortunately) all one line. Set applicable contexts to `Everywhere`.

With this live template it is now possible to type `todo`<kbd>Tab</kbd> somewhere in a source file and a line comment with the branch name will be inserted. This will insert the proper line comment depending on the language of the file, or nothing in case of languages without a line comment like HTML. And should extract the branch name no matter the type of version control used (I tested with Git).

Comment: This worked for years (thank you!) but stopped working in 2021.2 :(

Answer (score 1):

For live templates you can use [predefined functions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html). Unfortunately there is no function to detect the current VCS branch.
But you can create a template to make work a little easier:

```
// TODO [$branch_name$]: $comment$
```

With this template, you still have to fill branch name, but you should not type symbols like `[` and caret will be placed automatically.

You can also create a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) for a new predefined function.