# "com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationManager.getApplication()" is null when I'm trying to get all open projects

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, plugins

Here is my code :

```
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManager;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Project[] projects = ProjectManager.getInstance().getOpenProjects();
    for(Project project: projects) {
      System.out.println(project.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.getComponent(java.lang.Class)" because the return value of "com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationManager.getApplication()" is null
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManager.getInstance(ProjectManager.java:36)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6).
```

I want to know why and how to get all open projects. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

These classes are in the IntelliJ platform API, and must be run as a plugin in the IDEA main process but can't be run as a simple HelloWorld Java application. In other words, if you run it with `public static void main(String[] args) {`, there is no IDEA running at all, so all APIs will return null.

Please refer to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/creating-plugin-project.html for more info about how to create an IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: if we use these classes in live template groovy script, will it work or not?

Comment: No, it will not work, as it only allows some predefined variables here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.3/template-variables.html

Comment: In some cases, it is allowing to use classes as per this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896803/intellij-idea-live-templates

I have tested below script which includes existing Intellij classes and it is working fine :  `groovyScript("com.intellij.dvcs.repo.VcsRepositoryManager.getInstance(_editor.project).getRepositoryForFileQuick(com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getFile(_editor.document)).getCurrentBranchName()")`

Comment: Great, I tried and it does work. However, it's also defined as a prebuilt macro in class `com.intellij.codeInsight.template.macro.GroovyScriptMacro` and executed with a GroovyShell, which only provides `_editor` variable in the context, so if you want to use Java directly in this field, it's not supported. Still needs to create some plugin extension point like `<liveTemplateMacro implementation="com.intellij.codeInsight.template.macro.GroovyScriptMacro"/>`.